# How To Execute Solr Commit Before Closing The Web App?

Tags: web, solr, commit

Everyone. I Face A Problem In Solr Using, In Development Environment, Project Always Close And Start, Start And Close, When We Stop Tomcat, Some Solr Documents Are Remained Not Committed. How To Overcome This Headache, Can Anyone Show Some Ideas? Great Thanx.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shutdown hook within your webapplication to handle the shutdowns and commit the data.
Use a class that implements [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) in your web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <!-- Usual stuff here -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>solr.commitListerner</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Jayendra,thank you very much. It is really what I want to implement. I  started to use solr these months for the need of my work. What is your opinion about search big data with solr? such as, plenty of products of b2c website. I found it slowly and always cause outofmemory exception. searching among 20 thousand documents always cost 5 or 6 seconds, or little less. Maybe I have to optimize some code. Can you show me some advice? thanks.....

Comment: You should tune your schema and solr config for better handling of fields. Also check for the Caching part which can help you improve the performance.

Comment: hey,Jayendra. I added the code as you suggested, but unfortunately it didn't work. Its contextDestroyed method is not invoked when stopping the project. Can you give me some clue.....